# Poetry: build a package with a non-standard directory structure

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I created a repo with this non-standard structure:

```
- src
 - resources
  -- a.py
  -- b.py ...
```

I want to make a package out of it (let's call it `pack`).

In my pyproject.toml, the relevant lines are:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "pack"
include=[{include="src"}]
```

Then after a `pip install` everything is installed under src. Using it would mean `from src import ...` not `from pack import ...`.

If I follow the standard tree (everything under src/pack), then it works as expected.

**Question**

Is there a way, with my tree, to have the package built so as `from pack import ...` works?

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `pack` in your `import` statements, you need a folder that is called like this. This is how python discovers a package.

Where it is located and how your project is named is a different story. If you have a project structure like this:

```
pack
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── pack
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── a.py
        └── b.py
```

you must have this in your `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "pack"
packages = [{include = "pack", from = "src"}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wondered the top directory of the package had to be named as the package. Apparently yes, then.